# What does “as in” mean and can you use it like this?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

You’re spelling your name for someone on the phone and you say “N as in Never”. What does as in mean here? Could you say “N as in fun”?

Comment: Have you checked dictionary definitions of "as"? Like [the third one in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means: 'N' as *it is used* in 'Never'.

Whether you could use it as in your suggestion is arguable.

People expect you to be referring to the first letter in  a word when you are specifying a single letter.

However, if you were specifying a word, or syllable, you could certainly say something like: *"'key' as 'donkey'"*